# How to convert the value from getTimezoneOffset to a name for python pytz?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a time zone offset value from a website using:

```
var timezoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

The value gets passed into my python script. Then I am taking that value and applying it to all the different datetime.datetime objects I need.

```
dtNow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
timeDifference = datetime.timedelta(minutes=timezoneOffset)
dtNow = dtNow - timeDifference
```

How instead can I use that timezoneOffset value with pytz?
The arg in `tz = pytz.timezone(arg)` takes a string value such as 'US/Eastern'.
I am hoping there is a better way than creating my own dictionary of

```
{'US/Eastern': -300, 'US/Pacific': -480, ... }
```

::EDIT::

Running on Python 3.7

Comment: There can be multiple time different time zones which happen to have the same offset at one instant, but will differ later on. In other words, you're asking for something with no well-defined result.

Comment: If you want to create a fixed UTC offset, you can use the `timezone` class from the datetime module, which takes a timedelta to create. Btw. we have `zoneinfo` in the standard lib with Python 3.9, no need for pytz anymore.

Comment: Running on python 3.7

Comment: Basically, I'd suggest you pass a *date* to your Python script (ISO 8601 format string for example), not just an offset (see JonSkeet's comment). Then, if you just need to work with static offsets, the datetime module is sufficient. And finally, *if* working with time zones, you might want to use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), as it is much easier to replace with zoneinfo if you ever plan to upgrade to Py3.9 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do as you asked.  To understand why, see the section titled "Time Zone != Offset" in [the time zone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

*However*, you can instead gather the IANA time zone identifier directly from the web site using the following JavaScript:

```js
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

The result is a value such as `"America/Los_Angeles"` which you can pass to your Python back-end and use directly.